# sql query for fetching correct year

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table for structure like this

```
      ID    From_Year  From_Month  To_Year    To_Month    int
      1     2011        4          2012            3        8    
      2     2012        4          2013            3       8.6   
      3     2013        4          2014            3       8     
      4     2014        4          2014            8       8     
      5     2014        9          2015            3       8
```

from this table when supplied month and year  i need to fetch correct row from it 
for ex for

1-2012 row id 1

5-2013 row id 3

i have query as

```
   select * from tbl_fin where 
         (
           (From_month <=1 and From_Year =2014)  OR
           (To_month >= 1 and To_Year =2014)
         )
```

here 1 is given month and 2014 is given year

but it doesnt worked for 1-2014

can you suggest any other alternative

Comment: are those your exact column names? if so that's your problem - they'll want to be teh same in your definition as in your query (and they are CaseSensitive)

Comment: What does "correct row from it" means?
Assuming From_y, From_m is a start_date and to_y to_m is an end_date

What are you trying to read?
All records that start before a certain date and end after?
All records that start on a certain year or end on a certain year?

The query above selects all records that either start on 2014 before or during Jan or End on 2014 after or on Jan..

Comment: @odedsh means month=1 and year=2012 correct id is 1
and for month=5 and year=2013 correct id is 3

Comment: You want the records where the given date falls between FROM_MONTH/FROM_YEAR and TO_MONTH/TO_YEAR. The only reason the above sort of works so far is because you have ~1 record per year..

Follow the answer given by @MaGnetas.. convert to Date/Number for a more efficient solution

It will work if a single records spans 3 years.. or if a certain year has a record per month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tablename
WHERE
    CONCAT(from_y, LPAD(from_m, 2, 0)) <= '201201' AND
    CONCAT(to_y, LPAD(to_m, 2, 0)) >= '201201'
```

It's not very efficient though.
Basically you turn your from and to dates to YYYYMM format and then do a string comparison on both of them.

`LPAD(val, 2, 0)` makes sure your val is 2 digits long adding leading zero if needed. `CONCAT` joins year value with the left padded month value to a single string.

Then you need to make sure the date needed (I took 201201 from your example) is between from and to values.

More about:

[LPAD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

[CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Comment: The above is the correct way to go.. you can do it with numbers instead of strings though:

SELECT * From tbl_fin Where (<myYear>*100+<myM>) Between (FROM_Y*100 + FROM_M) AND (TO_Y*100 + TO_M)

Comment: Great idea. I believe this would be much faster too since string comparison (and other string operations) wouldn't be needed

Comment: I'd really suggest to go the way @odedsh suggested though. It's the same basic idea but a more "lightweight" solution.

Answer (score 1):

> select * from tablname where (to_year=2014 and to_month>1 and from_year<2014)

Comment: I don't believe this will return correct results in both given cases (2012 january or 2013 may)

Comment: select * from tablname where (to_year=2014 and to_month>1 and from_year<2014) or (from_year=2014 and from_month>=1 and to_year>2014 )

Comment: what if from year/month will be 2012/01 and to year/month will be 2015/05 and the needed date is 2013/07? This won't solve the problem

Comment: instead of to_year=2014  put to_year<2014
that could be managed as per the requirement